# Replace a string within quotes that succeeds a specific string using sed

Tags: replace, sed, text-processing

I have the following line:

KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false "

But I'm try to replace it with:

KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x  -Dremoting.bind_by_host=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false "

I tried using sed following this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66878/how-can-i-replace-text-after-a-specific-word-using-sed but with no luck.

The issue is because of the double quotes. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have

```
line='KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false "'
```

Then you can do

```
$ line=$(sed '
    s/"/"Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x /
    s/authenticate/&=false/
' <<<"$line")
$ echo "$line"
KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false "
```